# Use generic interface in Moq with CQRS pattern

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I have an interface ICommand -> marker interface:

```
public interface ICommand
{
}
```

another interface ICommandHandle:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    Task HandleAsync(T command);
}
```

Next is ICommandDispatcher:

```
public interface ICommandDispatcher : ICommand
{
    Task DispatchAsync<T>(T command) where T : ICommand; 
}
```

and the CommandDispatcher class:

```
public class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _context;

    public CommandDispatcher(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        _context = componentContext;
    }

    public async Task DispatchAsync<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
    {
        if (command == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command), "Command can not be null");

        var handler = _context.Resolve<ICommandHandler<T>>();
        await handler.HandleAsync(command);
    }
}
```

I'm writing a unit test which will check if the a user exists or not.
I want to invoke my handler and go through the whole process like create user, validate input parameters etc. Of course in memory, I won't connect to my real database in this case. And my question is if this code is correct.

```
var commandDispatcher = new Mock<ICommandHandler<CreateUser>>();
var command = new CreateUser
{
    Name = "user",
    Email = "user@email.com"
};

var client = new Client("user", "user@email.com");
commandDispatcher.Setup(x => x.HandleAsync(command));
```

I'm wondering should I use in test

```
new Mock<ICommandHandler>
```

or

```
new Mock<ICommandDispatcher>
```

After reading the comments below I'm just wondering if I confused unit test with integration test?

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: "I'm writing unit test which will be check that user exist or not." - is this an **actual** _unit test_, or are you misusing the term "unit test" when you really mean _integration test_?

Comment: Is `ICommandHandler` itself generic? Where/how is `T command` defined?

Comment: I corrected my post, please give me more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this tutorial good: https://youtu.be/ub3P8c87cwk

Also Unit testing can mean something as "Testing one particular class".
So you can test that CreateUserHandler is correctly calling HandleAsync().
But you cant actualy test whether user is created, because it is  action that requires multiple "units" to be called. For this the integration tests are usually used.

Comment: So is this a unit test: I invoke my handler for example which create new user. And I put in name property white space, this test invoke my handler and return error like parameter can not be null or white space ? Is this a unit test or integration test ?

Comment: In this case you can unit test the 'unit' wich is responsible for validating the 'creating custumer' request. But the question is who is responsible for this validation? The invoked handler or something else?. If you structured your code that the handler is the one responsible for validation then you can create unit test method/s for handlerClass that checks if validation rules are applied when handler.invoke is called with incorrect data

Comment: if your handler is the one validation the request then yes a method(test) that is checking if your handler is throwing exception is unit test